# Find the number of homomorphisms between cyclic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> In each of the following examples determine the number of homomorphisms between the given groups:
>
> $(a)$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$;
>
> $(b)$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$;
>
> $(c)$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Could anyone just give me hints for the problem? Well, let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ be homo, then $f(1)=[n]$ for any $[n]\in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ will give a homomorphism hence there are $10$ for (a)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. f(1) is all that matters, because 1 generates the whole group.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807358/number-of-homomorphisms-between-two-cyclic-groups) is a related post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Hint:***

A homomorphism on a *cyclic group* is completely determined by its value on a *generator* of the group.

---

***Edit***:

Your thoughts on $(a)$ are indeed correct.

Use similar reasoning, along with the given hint to arrive at answers for $(b)$ and $(c)$. See what you can do, and I'll be happy to follow up in comments.

---

Comment: Is it 10 for (b) and (c) as well?

Comment: No i think its $10$ for (b) and $5$ for (C).

Comment: @Kns, there are only 2 for (c), i.e. $f(1)=[5]$ and $f(1)=[0]$. The only possibilities to define $f:\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ on a generator is to map $1$ to a multiple of $\frac{m}{gcd(m,n)}$. (Try to figure out why). There are thus $gcd(m,n)$ possibilities.