# Number of homomorphisms between two cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Is it true that the number of homomorphisms between any two finite cyclic groups of order $m\,\&\,n$ is $\gcd(m,n)$?

I have posted an answer which I believe is true, just wanted to know different approaches to this problem.

Comment: Yes it is. Consider the generators.

Comment: @AdamHughes Sure about that? Details?

Comment: @AdamHughes Eergh. Never mind. Thanks. Sorry.

Comment: Before some users vote to close this question for the lack of context, I will point out that the OP posted their own proof as an answer. (I guess showing your own work counts as context. Maybe the fact that the OP posted their attempt as an answer could be mentioned in the post.)

Comment: [This blogpost](https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/homomorphisms-between-finitely-generated-abelian-groups-pt-i/) and [this post on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120861/homomorphism-between-cyclic-groups) seem to be related.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let us consider homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_m\to\mathbb Z_n$. Let us denote $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

---

Since $1$ is generator of $\mathbb Z_m$, the choice of $f(1)=a\in\mathbb Z_n$ uniquely determines all values of $f$. Namely we get
$$f(k) = f(k\times 1)= k\times f(1) = k\times a.$$
(Here $k\times b$ denotes the addition $\underset{\text{$k$-times}}{\underbrace{b\oplus b\oplus \dots\oplus b}}$, where $\oplus$ denotes the addition in the given group, in this case either $\mathbb Z_m$ or $\mathbb Z_n$. I chose this notation to distinguish it from the usual addition of integers.)

But not all choices of $a$ are possible. We definitely need
$$f(0) = f(m\times 1) = m\times a = 0.$$
I.e., $ma \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

This gives us that $ma=nb$ for some integer $b$. If we divide both sides by $d$, we get
$$\frac md a = \frac nd b.$$
Since $\frac nd$ and $\frac md$ are coprime, this implies that $$\frac nd \mid a.$$

But there are exactly $d$ such numbers in $\mathbb Z_n$, namely the numbers $0,\frac{n}d, \frac{2n}d,\dots, \frac{(d-1)n}d$.

So we see that there are **at most** $d$ homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_m\to\mathbb Z_n$.

---

It remains to check somehow that for any choice of $a$ such that $m\times a=0$ (i.e., one of the $a$'s described above) the function given by
$$f(k) = k\times a$$
is indeed a homomorphism.

If $k,l\in\mathbb Z_m$, then we want to check whether
$$f(k\oplus l) = f(k) \oplus f(l),$$
i.e., whether
$$((k+l)\bmod m)\times a = (k\times a + l\times a)\bmod n.$$
We can write
$$((k+l)\bmod m)\times a \overset{(1)}=
(k+l)\times a \overset{(2)}=
k\times a \oplus l\times a \overset{(3)}=
 (k\times a + l\times a)\bmod n.$$
$(1)$ is true since $m\times a=0$
$(2)$ follows simply from properties of groups. (I will link to a [similar proof for rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530720/proof-of-m-times-a-n-times-a-m-n-times-a-in-rings). But the basic idea is the same and this should be fairly obvious.)
$(3)$ is simply the definition of the operation $\oplus$ on the group $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: How does $m\times a = 0$ imply $(1)$? Also how exactly does $(2)$ follow? It's LHS is (e.g. for $a=3$) $(k+l)+(k+l)+(k+l)=(k+k+k)+(l+l+l)=k\times 3+l\times 3$, but why does it also equal $k\times 3+l\times 3 \mod n$?

Comment: @user5579085 In $(1)$ the difference between the LHS and RHS is a multiple of $m\times a$. (This is the difference $(k+l)\times a - ((k+l)\bmod m) \times a$ and $(k+l)-((k+l)\bmod m)$ is a multiple of $m$. For $(2)$ I have provided link in the post.

Comment: Maybe I could also add that $(2)$ basically says this: $\underset{\text{$k+l$-times}}{\underbrace{a\oplus a\oplus \dots\oplus a}}=\underset{\text{$k$-times}}{\underbrace{a\oplus a\oplus \dots\oplus a}}\oplus\underset{\text{$l$-times}}{\underbrace{a\oplus a\oplus \dots\oplus a}}$. So I think it is intuitively clear. But if you want a bit more formal proof of this, you can still have a look at that link.

Answer (score 9):

Set $d=\gcd(m,n),\enspace n'=\dfrac nd$. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z,\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)$ is in bijection with 
\begin{align*}\{x+n\mathbf Z\,; m(x+n\mathbf Z)=n\mathbf Z \}&=\{x+n\mathbf Z\,; n\mid mx \} =\Bigl\{x+n\mathbf Z\,; \dfrac n{\gcd(m,n)}\,\Big\vert\, x \Bigr\}\\[1ex]&=n'\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z=n'\mathbf Z/n'd\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/d\mathbf Z.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

This can be proved with the help of these theorems.

1)Lagrange's Theorem.

2)If $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\hat G$ and let $g\in G$. Then if $|g|=k$, then $|\phi(g)|$ divides $k$.

[3)$\gcd(n,m)=\sum_{d|n\,and\,d|m}\varphi(d)$, $\varphi$ being the Euler's totient function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807820/relation-between-gcd-and-eulers-totient-function?noredirect=1#comment3694334_1807820)

4)If $d$ is a positive divisor of $k$, the number of elements of order $d$ in a cyclic group of order $k$ is $\varphi(d)$.

> Every cyclic group of order $k$ is isomorphic to $Z_k$.If $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$ observe that once we know $\phi(1)$ we know $\phi(k)$ for any $k,$ because $\phi(k)=\phi\underbrace{(1+1+\cdots+1)}_{k \text{ terms}}=\underbrace{\phi(1)+\phi(1)+\cdots \phi(1)}_{k \text{ terms}}=k\phi(1).$ 
>    Hence a homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$ is completely determined by the image of $1 \in Z_m$. If $1$ maps to $a$, by $(2)$ and $(1)$ respectively $|a|$ should divide both $m$ and $n$; so that $|a|$ is a common divisor of $m$ and $n$.
>
> Now the problem breaks down to finding the no. of elements in $Z_n$ such that their orders divide both $m$ and $n.$
>
> Let $d$ be any positive common divisor of $m$ and $n$. The number of elements of order $d$ in $Z_n$ is $\varphi(d)$ by $(4)$. Thus the number of candidates for $a$ is $\sum_{d|m\,and\,d|n}\varphi(d)$. Invoking $(3)$, this is nothing but $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: Maybe you could add to your answer link to your other post where the proof of expressing $\gcd(m,n)$ using totient function can be found.

Comment: If we denote the cyclic groups by $G$ and $H,$ we could arrive at the number $\sum_{d\mid m,n}\varphi(d)$ as follows: since $G=\langle g\rangle$ is finite, if $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism, as a consequence of the first isomorphism theorem, we have $m=|\ker f|\cdot|\operatorname{im}f|.$ Since $G$ is cyclic and $\ker f\le G,$ so is $\ker f$ and $$\ker f=\langle g^k\rangle=\{e,g^k,\ldots, g^{k(|\ker f|-1)}\}$$ for some $ 0\le k\le m-1,k\color{red}\mid m.$ If $0<i<j<k, f(g^i)\ne f(g^j),$ otherwise, $e=f(g^j)f(g^i)^{-1}=f(g^{j-i}),$ but $j-i\in\{1,\ldots,k-2\},$ which is impossible.

Comment: Since $f(g^{i+k})=f(g^i)f(g^k)=f(g^i),$ we conclude the same for elements from other "intervals". Therefore, $\operatorname{im}f$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $k$ in $H.$ But, $k=|\operatorname{im}f|$ must divide both $|G|$ and $|H|.$ For each divisor $d,$ $H$ has a unique cyclic subgroup of order $d.$ In particular that holds for common divisors of $m$ and $n.$ Each such subgroup has $\varphi(d)$ generators.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f:Z/m\rightarrow Z/n$, set $f([1])=[p]$, $f(m[1])=f([m])=0$. this implies $m[p]=0$ in $Z/n$ thus $mp=0 $ mod $n$, thus ${n\over {\gcd(n,m)}}$ divides $p$. The number of morphisms between $Z/m$ and $Z/m$ is the order of the subgroup of $Z/n$ generated by $[{n\over {\gcd(n,m)}}]$  which is $\gcd(n,m)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be the g.c.d. of $m$ and $n$. We will denote the coset $k+\langle n\rangle$ by $[k]$. Let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ generated by $[n/d]$. As the order of $[n/d]$ is $d$, it follows that $|H|=d$. So for any $[k]\in H$, we see that the order of $[k]$ divides $d$.

Suppose $[k]\in\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ such that the order of $[k]$ divides $d$. Then $[dk]=d[k]=[0]$ and so $n$ divides $dk$. It follows that $n/d$ divides $k$ and hence $[k]\in \langle \,[n/d]\,\rangle$. So we have shown that the set of all the elements in $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ whose order divides $d$ is the subgroup $H$.

We now use the fact that for any group $G$, we have a bijection given by
the map

$\varphi:\{f:\mathbb Z/\langle m\rangle \to G\mid f$ is a homomorphism$\}\to \{x\in G\mid x^m=e\}$ which is defined as $\varphi(f)=f(\,[1]\,)$.

We claim that the set of all elements in $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ whose order divides $m$ is equal to the subgroup $H$ which was defined earlier. Observe that by using the mentioned fact and claim, we are done.

Let $[k]\in \mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ such that the order of $[k]$ divides $m$. The order of $[k]$ also divides the order of $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ which is $n$. So it follows that the order of $[k]$ divides $d$ and hence $[k]\in H$. Conversely, as the order of any element $[k]\in H$ divides $d$, it also divides $m$. This proves our claim.