# Find homomorphism between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

The task is to find all the Homomorphisms from group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$.
My teacher told be that there is an sufficient way to do this, however I've just brute forced it. Do you have any ideas? Would be grateful for the answer also, just to check my own one.

Comment: This has been asked very often here (search a bit). For general $n$ and $m$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807358/number-of-homomorphisms-between-two-cyclic-groups).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks! And do you know any website that can help me to check my answer?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate. Take $n=20$ and $m=16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ideas that might be easier than brute force.

- Since the domain is a cyclic group, every homomorphism is determined
  by where it sends a generator. What are the possibilities?
- The quotient of the domain modulo the kernel of a homomorphism will
  be isomorphic to a subgroup of the codomain.